# This method(chr()) does not support unicode in crystal report.. so how to use unicode in crystal?

Tags: unicode, crystal-reports

I used chr(252) for tick mark in crystal report, this tick mark displayed in chrome, IE Except Firefox.. Firefox won't support windings font, so i have to used unicode..

These are the unicode for tick mark (U+2713 Hex) and (10003D), Now, by which method or way or technique i can use these unicode??

Please, reply me asap...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't get any method to use unicode as a parameter..  but i got my solution...

In crystal report formula, i used html tag( `<font> &#10003; </font>` ) and set to this field into HTML Text by Format Object option..

Now, its work....

Comment: Saved my effort, was looking for this solution.